# getRequest from another action in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, http-request

I'm considering that is there any chance to `getRequest` from another action in Magento. For example, I have an action called `registerAction()` which is the action I submit data from my form to. I have another action called `ajaxAction()` which I want to use the submit data from `registerAction`

The question is: Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried forwarding the request i.e. `$this->_forward('ajax');` from `registerAction()`?

Comment: @JonathanHussey: I didn't, what is `_forward()` ?

Comment: It's a method you can use to forward (not redirect) requests to any another action - see the protected `_forward()` method in class `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`, it's probably what you are after.

Comment: @JonathanHussey make a answer for this because it is what  the answer should be

Answer (score 0):

Without more detailed information on what you're trying to achieve, it will be difficult to provide an answer.

**If both of the actions are being performed in one request:**
Example: Customer goes to `www.example.com/my_action` which triggers the `registerAction()` and the `ajaxAction()`

In the `registerAction()` function

```
$quote->setMyData("the data to store.");
```

In the `ajaxAction()` function

```
$quote->getMyData();
```

This is assuming you have access to the quote object already. If not, use this code before those two lines

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```